# rvest web scraping from html page

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I'm trying to scrape bookies odds from this page :

https://www.interwetten.com/en/sportsbook/top-leagues?topLinkId=1

so I wrote the following code so far

```
interwetten <- read_html("https://www.interwetten.com/en/sportsbook/top-leagues?topLinkId=1") 
bundesliga <- html_nodes(interwetten, xpath = '//*[@id="TBL_Content_1019"]')  
bundesliga_teams <- html_nodes(bundesliga, "span")
```

and now the output I get is:

```
[1] <span id="ctl00_cphMain_UCOffer_LeagueList_rptLeague_ctl00_ucBettingContainer_lblClose" clas ...
[2] <span itemscope="itemscope" itemprop="location" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><meta ite ...
[3] <span itemprop="name">VfB Stuttgart</span>
[4] <span>X</span>
```

Now I want to extract the team name inside **every** `<span itemprop="name"></span>` but I don't know how to extract it. I tried to use nodes or attrs but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the XPath selector more specific and then use `html_text`, e.g.

```r
library(rvest)

interwetten <- 'https://www.interwetten.com/en/sportsbook/top-leagues?topLinkId=1' %>% 
    read_html() 

teams <- interwetten %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="TBL_Content_1019"]//span[@itemprop="name"]') %>% 
    html_text()

teams
#>  [1] "VfB Stuttgart"   "1. FC Cologne"   "Mainz 05"       
#>  [4] "Hamburger SV"    "Hertha BSC"      "Schalke 04"     
#>  [7] "Hannover 96"     "Frankfurt"       "Hoffenheim"     
#> [10] "Augsburg"        "Bayern Munich"   "Freiburg"       
#> [13] "Dortmund"        "RB Leipzig"      "Leverkusen"     
#> [16] "Wolfsburg"       "Werder Bremen"   "Monchengladbach"
```

Comment: thank you very much! would you mind guiding me how to insert those team names into a dataframe of two columns? I want every team with odd index no' (1, 3, 5..) be inserted in the first column and the every team indexed in a even position will be in the second column?

Comment: You could use `tibble::as_data_frame(matrix(teams, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))` after the fact. It's more robust to scrape each into a separate vector, but it's a little more work.